# RegEx : Match line of string that does not contain [ character

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

Another RegEx question that I could not solve myself:

I have this JavaScript file with the following content:

```
var myApp = new App();
function ExplicitFunction ( one, two, three ) {
}

/** This line should match from .add ("ModuleA", ExplicitFunction ) { */
myApp.add ("ModuleA", ExplicitFunction ) {
}

/** This line should not match at all because of [ character after "ModuleB",  */
myApp.add ("ModuleB", ["p1", "p2", function (p1, p2) {
}]);


/** This line should match from .add ("ModuleC", function(paramA, paramB) { */
myApp.add ("ModuleC", function(paramA, paramB) {
});
```

Based from the codes above, I want to write a RegEx that will find from this file those codes that are not following this coding convention; **Please note of the array parameter**.

```
.add ("Some String Here", [ anything here string or function ]);
```

So Basically, As what the comments /** */ on the file is describing

```
myApp.add ("ModuleB", ["p1", "p2", function (p1, p2) {
}]);
```

should not match because it follows the  coding convention describe above.

and the other lines that is calling myApp.add should match because it does not follow the convention.

I have tried the following :

```
\.add\s*\({1}.*[^\[]\w*
```

[Demo Here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5C.add%5Cs%2a%5C%28%7B1%7D.%2a%5B%5E%5C%5B%5D%5Cw%2a&input=var%20myApp%20=%20new%20App%28%29;%0Afunction%20ExplicitFunction%20%28%20one,%20two,%20three%20%29%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0A/%2a%2a%20This%20line%20should%20match%20from%20.add%20%28%22ModuleA%22,%20ExplicitFunction%20%29%20%7B%20%2a/%0AmyApp.add%20%28%22ModuleA%22,%20ExplicitFunction%20%29%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0A/%2a%2a%20This%20line%20should%20not%20match%20at%20all%20because%20of%20%5B%20character%20after%20%22ModuleB%22,%20%20%2a/%0AmyApp.add%20%28%22ModuleB%22,%20%5B%22p1%22,%20%22p2%22,%20function%20%28p1,%20p2%29%20%7B%0A%7D%5D%29;%0A%0A%0A/%2a%2a%20This%20line%20should%20match%20from%20.add%20%28%22ModuleC%22,%20function%28paramA,%20paramB%29%20%7B%20%2a/%0AmyApp.add%20%28%22ModuleC%22,%20function%28paramA,%20paramB%29%20%7B%0A%7D%29;)

But it selects everything from .add string.

Can anyone point me to the the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
\.add *\([^,]+, +[^[][^{]*{$
```

with `g` and `m` flags.

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/mD9iX0)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
\.add\s*\([^\[\n]*{$
```

`.add`, then possible whitespace, then `(`, then stuff that is not `[` or a line-break, and finally a `{` closing the line.

All this with a `\m` switch that makes `$` match end of the line.

It could of course be improved and tailored to your needs, but might be a good start.

- [Demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5C.add%5Cs%2a%5C%28%5B%5E%5C%5B%5D%2a%7B%24&input=var%20myApp%20=%20new%20App%28%29;%0Afunction%20ExplicitFunction%20%28%20one,%20two,%20three%20%29%20%7B%0A%7D%0A%0A/%2a%2a%20This%20line%20should%20match%20from%20.add%20%28%22ModuleA%22,%20ExplicitFunction%20%29%20%7B%20%2a/%0AmyApp.add%20%28%22ModuleA%22,%20ExplicitFunction%20%29%20%7B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0A/%2a%2a%20This%20line%20should%20not%20match%20at%20all%20because%20of%20%5B%20character%20after%20%22ModuleB%22,%20%20%2a/%0AmyApp.add%20%28%22ModuleB%22,%20%5B%22p1%22,%20%22p2%22,%20function%20%28p1,%20p2%29%20%7B%0A%7D%5D%29;%0A%0A%0A/%2a%2a%20This%20line%20should%20match%20from%20.add%20%28%22ModuleC%22,%20function%28paramA,%20paramB%29%20%7B%20%2a/%0AmyApp.add%20%28%22ModuleC%22,%20function%28paramA,%20paramB%29%20%7B%0A%7D%29;)
- [And a little explanation](http://regex101.com/r/nZ2wD0)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This seems to be fine until I moved the { to the  next line.  +1 because it's close